# NetBeans Deployment error: Starting of server GlassFish Server is not supported

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish-4.1

I am using NetBeans 8.2, GlassFish4.1. When I right click my Java Web project and deploy, a GlassFish Administration Credential window pop up, and an error occurs as follows:

Deployment error: Starting of server GlassFish Server is not supported. Please, start the server manually.

[image]

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setting password for admin and enable secure admin. Use the following command would help:

```
adadmin
change-admin-password
```

Please notice that the default user name is admin, default password is empty(just press enter).

```
enable-secure-admin
```

Enter user name and the new password you have just set.

```
restart-domain
```

[image]